# Restrict user registration only to specific email addresses or specific GSuite Groups?

Tags: php, laravel, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to restrict registration and login access to my Laravel application using Socialite to a specific set of users. These users have been configured to be classified within the same GSuite Group, and I was wondering if there is anyway that I can restrict access to only this group of users.

I've tried to restrict registration to only Specific Domain Names using the following callback function:

```
public function handleCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        // only allow users with @company.com to login
        if (explode("@", $user->email)[1] !== 'company.com') {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
        // check if they're an existing user
        $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
        if ($existingUser) {
            // log them in
            auth()->login($existingUser, true);
        } else {
            // create a new user
            $newUser                  = new User;
            $newUser->name            = $user->name;
            $newUser->email           = $user->email;
            $newUser->google_id       = $user->id;
            $newUser->avatar          = $user->avatar;
            $newUser->avatar_original = $user->avatar_original;
            $newUser->save();
            auth()->login($newUser, true);
        }
        return redirect()->to('/home');
    }
```

However, this doesn't restrict the app entirely, as all users within my organisation is able to register. Is there any workaround to this?